# How can we change gender preference into dichotomous variable when the categories are male, female or any in order to conduct logistics regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

How can we change gender into dichotomous variable when the categories are male, female or any in order to conduct logistics regression?

My research is about gender preferences at the time of birth, and I categories gender preference variable as male, female, or any.

How can we convert it into two categories? How can I conduct logistics analysis?

Comment: Why do you want to run a logistic regression? It will be easier to help you if you explain what your research question is.

Comment: If you are assuming more genders than "male" and "female" feel free to remove the "binary data" tag

Comment: Research question: Effect of age, household income, level of education, religion and interests/ habits on gender preference.

Comment: See the IDRE page on multinomial logistic regression in SPSS https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/

Comment: I have tried to use multinational logistic regression but it shows following error:There are 76 (66.7%) cells (i.e., dependent variable levels by subpopulations) with zero frequencies.

Comment: Unexpected singularities in the Hessian matrix are encountered. This indicates that either some predictor variables should be excluded or some categories should be merged.

Comment: The NOMREG procedure continues despite the above warning(s). Subsequent results shown are based on the last iteration. Validity of the model fit is uncertain.

Comment: Please advise me on this

Comment: "any" means "i do not care it's boy or girl"? In your dataset,how many girls, boys and "any"s? From your description, it seems you have very limited number of "any"s.

Answer (score 1):

Since `any` would encompass either value for the categorical variable, this would still be a single dichotomous indicator variable and the results indicating `any` gender would be coded as missing values (i.e., as `NA`).  When conducting logistic regression with this  as one of your explanatory variables, you can employ standard methods to handle missing data (e.g., multiple imputation or Bayesian methods).  If gender is your response (which seems to be the case from the comments) then these data points are effectively useless, since there is no specified response.

Comment: I am using SPSS. I do not want to code any as missing values, because it shows the people having no gender preference at all, which is the center of my study.

Comment: The class ```any``` literally means that *any* gender could be subsumed by that label.  Hence, the specification of a particular gender is missing.  If you don't want to code it as that, that is up to you.

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by subsum? @Ben

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subsume

Answer (score 1):

You could view this situation as an attempt to use an underlying latent variable for gender preference ranging from strongly prefer a girl through neutral to strongly prefer a boy. What you have actually observed is the latent variable cut into three categories. This seems to be the model which underlies ordered categorical regression so I would suggest fitting that model. You attempt to use multinomial logistic is also possible but it does not take account of the ordered nature  of your three categories. I am afraid I do not use SPSS so cannot tell you which command to use but [this page](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/) is from a usually very helpful site.